# border on hover element of list

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with list in html.

I want a basic functionality: when user hover on an element of the list, its border-top-color and his sibling changes to red;

So if I have HTML like this:

```html
<dl>
  <dt>Example 1</dt>
  <dd>Description 1</dd>

  <dt>Example 2</dt>
  <dd>Description 2</dd>

  <dt>Example 3</dt>
  <dd>Description 3</dd>
</dl>
```

and CSS:

```css
dd {
    display: none;
}

dt {
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}

dt:last-of-type {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

dt:hover {
    border-top: 1px solid red;
}

dt:hover:last-of-type {
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}

dt:hover + dd + dt {
    border-top: 1px solid red;
}
```

I don't get the expected result. If I hover on the first element, only top-border changes to red. If I hover on the third element, then on the second and then on the first, the border changes to red for second element and first, but should only to first on the last state. Why does it happen?

Comment: Could you provide us a http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: can you please explain what are you calling an element? is it the title (dt) or the description (dd)? also, what changes to red? both the title and description's top borders, or just the title?

Comment: Strange, I see the border remaining red even after hovering over the third `<dt>` in Chrome 27 but not FF 21 .. is that what you're referring to?

Comment: @Adrift I see the same odd behaviour as you describe, and only in Chrome 27 (using the demo by Zenith). IE 10 and FF 21 behave as expected.

Comment: Apparently it's a bug in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a case of a Webkit bug with multiple adjacent siblings that's been around for years. See [one of many reports](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=174886). I tested in Firefox 21 and IE10 without issues.

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/kkoala/3nwje/2/) a modified version of Zenith's fiddle that demonstrates correct behaviour for *one* adjacent sibling selector in Chrome/Webkit. I omitted the `dd`'s and adjusted the CSS selector to `dt:hover + dt` (just to demonstrate; this doesn't make sense, of course).

There have been CSS hacks to work around the issue, but they cause problems on certain platforms. Your best option is probably to achieve the desired effect using a different approach.

(Sorry, this probably belongs in the comments to your question, but I still lack the required reputation)

Comment: I see that it behaves as I expect in Firefox, but it seems to be a bug in Webkit as you said. Now I need to think how to get around this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I fixed it by adding single line:

```
dt:hover ~ dt {}
```

Now it works in Chrome, too.